# Repairing cracks in sneaker treads

Tags: repair

I have a pair of Jordan 1 low and today I found out that the midsole of the shoe start having cracks. I am thinking if I can use any rubber mould to cover those crack or if there are any other ways to help to cover the cracks on the midsole. If you could help, that will mean the world to me. Because that Jordan is my favourite shoe. It has been with me for 10 years, so please help.

Comment: If you can get the gel version of superglue, that will work - but not for long, in my experience, unfortunately, Otherwise, take 'em to a shoe repairer, see if they've got a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Styrene-butadiene rubber cements (glues), that is, styrene-butadiene copolymer dissolved in an organic solvent, such as [Shoe Goo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoe_Goo), is effective.

Clean and wire-brush the sole before applying, force the goo into the cracks, and try to shape it to the tread pattern with a popsicle stick.

In my experience, it adheres fairly well, but eventually wears a bit faster than the original rubber sole.

**N.B.** If the sole has started to crack, then you'll find many more forming, though.